# How to configure incProgress() dynamically when using withProgress()?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm really struggling to understand how to increment the progress bar using `withProgress()`. How do I get the exact time needed to complete my task and sync it to the bar progress?

Consider this example on exporting a SVM Model, it may take a while, how do I set the `incProgress` ? Actually its stucking at more or less 10% of its size and then it closes when the task is finished.

```
output$download_SV <- downloadHandler(

                filename = function() {
                  "model_svm_reg.rds"
                },
                content = function(fname) {
                  withProgress(message = 'Exporting model, please wait ...', {
                  incProgress(?)
                  saveRDS(fit_SV(), fname)
                  })
                }
              )
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, the `withProgress` works so that you need to update/increment the progress bar manually. From what I know, there is no way to know how much of the model has been imported, which is probably why you get 10% and 100% values. See [this example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/withProgress.html) and notice how they use a `for` loop to increment. Each iteration would represent one step. In your code, you have... one step.

Comment: Yes, but since there's no way to know how much of the model has been imported, how do I set the steps and the sleep interval?
In this case The bar can finish and the process dont and vice versa

Comment: From what I understand, you can have one step before starting the import and another one after the import has been done. You don't need to set any sleep intervals, that's there just so that you get to see the effect of progress.